# Application Logging into Azure Blob Storage or use log4net into SQL

Tags: azure, logging, log4net, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage

I'm quite new in Development for Azure, I have a asp.net mvc 4 application in a Azure Cloud Service.

I have a application that has a considering quantity of transaction providing by API and I need to implement some applications loggings for improve the daily diagnostic, I'm looking for a tutorial that store those into a Blob Storage instead of SQL Database, but without relevant success.

Blob Storage sounds good because I don't need to increase substantially my database that also has all the business data and could compromise a business resource (Database) becoming slower because of log transactions.

If I decide to go to storage in SQL database I'm thinking in use Log4Net.

What you guys suggest and send me tutorial that I can follow, please.

Thank you.

Comment: Consider to use Semantic Logging from the Enterprise Library (http://slab.codeplex.com/) and save the logs in the table storage. It contains an out of process service to support high volumes of log message and won't hurt your application performance

Comment: SQL Database will certainly cost you more than logging to Table Storage.  Have you looked into the standard [Azure Diagnostics plugin](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-diagnostics/) for web and worker roles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry our logging guidance is a little hard to find - something that we are currently working on resolving - but for now please take a look at the following resources:

[Client logging overview](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/09/07/announcing-storage-client-library-2-1-rtm.aspx)  - Essentially all client library operations are output using System.Diagnostics, so you intercept and write to text / xml file just using a standard TraceListener.

[Analytics and Server logs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2011/08/03/windows-azure-storage-logging-using-logs-to-track-storage-requests.aspx) - We have extensive service side logging capabilities as well - which troubleshooting distributed apps much simpler.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Jason

Comment: Might I'm wrong but this don't allow me to create custom logs right?
And also I didn't find out how to implement it into my solution.